# Using EXPECT_CALL for local methods

Tags: c++, googletest

I know `EXPECT_CALL` is supposed to be used for mocked classes and their objects/methods.  But is it ever possible to use this to expect calls of local methods?

```
void Sample::Init()
{
   // some codes here...

   auto enabled = isFeatureEnabled();

   //some other things here
}

bool Sample::isFeatureEnabled()
{
   return lights_ and sounds_;
}
```

I want to EXPECT_CALL `isFeatureEnabled()` - is this at all possible?

Comment: Short answer: Not without rewriting part of the class. You can only mock methods that are accessed thorugh some kind of dependency injection.

Comment: Thought so too. Guess I will modify implementation to be more testable. Thanks for the confirmation! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this, I find this approach useful:

```
class template_method_base {
public:
  void execute(std::string s1, std::string s2) {
    delegate(s1 + s2);
  }

private:
  virtual void delegate(std::string s) = 0;
};

class template_method_testable : public template_method_base {
public:
  MOCK_METHOD1(delegate, void(std::string s));
};

TEST(TestingTemplateMethod, shouldDelegateCallFromExecute) {
  template_method_testable testable_obj{};

  EXPECT_CALL(testable_obj, delegate("AB"));

  testable_obj.execute("A", "B");
}
```